# Zend Framework 2 mailing not working on CentOS 7

Tags: php, zend-framework2, centos7

Basically there is a custom class Mail that extends Zend\Mail\Message and uses Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp to send mails with HTML template, it works very nice, it's not written by me. It was working on a ubuntu server and it works on localhost, but it's not working on a CentOS 7 server.
I've tried everything there it is on the web, "service sendmail restart/start/status" returns No such file or directory even though which sendmail shows /usr/sbin/sendmail. I'm not very familiar with linux.

Comment: mail() function doesn't send anything, while trying to send email the zend way I get "Incorrect authentication data" exception

Comment: I did the steps from here
https://lecturesnippets.com/lesson/sending-email-through-the-centos-7-php-web-server/

Comment: If you are using the SMTP transport, you're sending through SMTP, not sendmail. The error suggests your SMTP credentials are incorrect. Since you're trying to set it up on a different OS, it could also be that the new host can't send through your chosen SMTP server.

Comment: You don't need postfix in the same way that you don't need sendmail. Your application is attempting to connect to a SMTP server directly to send email. You don't need any local MTAs (or other libraries) to do this.